# Adding TinySlider to Magento 2 Custom Module

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.3

I have been tasked with developing a USP banner. This banner is to display simple, short and snappy items to the entailing user.

I have been looking at using TinySlider(OwlCarousel) to help add a simple animation to the different items (Carousel of items). For example, The ability to have the banner scroll automatically to display the multiple items (more than 6) that have been created within the Magento 2 backend. Adding the ability for the user to click and drag the USP Banner is also essential with this module.

The problem I have encountered trying this myself is not knowing what files from the TinySlider download directory are actually needed and what isn't. adding to this, I was wondering where the files from this directory get added to?

My assumption would be that it gets added to the view/frontend/web/js folder of the module.

I'm open to any suggestions on alternative methods of achieving this.

Comment: If you are happy to run the files from a CDN then there is no need to download any files you should just be able to include the JS files as part of your require js config ready to use to acheive what your after